Echart | Vertical timeline chart data getting cropped
I'm creating a timeline chart to plot events for a specific date using apache echart. The gap between events is determined by the time difference between them, with minimum and maximum gap constraints. However, my chart is getting cropped instead of utilizing the available space (chart height). Even though the data zoom slider is at the end, the rest of the chart is not visible. Can anyone help me identify the issue and suggest a solution.
Chart Code in echart editor
Relevant part of echart code is:
let event_data = {
  '2024-03-22': [
    ['DEVICE_SLEEP', 'DEVICE_SLEEP', '07:51:35'],
    ['DEVICE_SLEEP', 'DEVICE_SLEEP', '07:59:44'],
    ['DEVICE_SLEEP', 'DEVICE_SLEEP', '08:37:49'],
    ['DEVICE_STREAM', 'DEVICE_STREAM', '12:09:29'],
    ['DEVICE_RESET', 'DEVICE_RECORD', '12:10:39'],
    ['DEVICE_RECORD', 'DEVICE_RECORD', '12:10:40'],
    ['DEVICE_RESET', 'DEVICE_START', '12:10:54'],
    ['DEVICE_RESET', 'DEVICE_SLEEP', '12:20:29'],
    ['DEVICE_STREAM', 'DEVICE_STREAM', '12:29:28'],
    ['DEVICE_SLEEP', 'DEVICE_SLEEP', '22:43:05']
  ]
};
const chartHeight = myChart.getHeight();
const chartWidth = myChart.getWidth();
const maxVisibleYAxisValue = chartHeight;

function timeToSeconds(time) {
  const [hours, minutes, seconds] = time.split(':').map(Number);
  return hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds;
}
//ProcessData function to dynamically assign Y-axis positions
function processData(dateKey) {
  const events = event_data[dateKey];
  let prevTimeInSeconds = 0;
  const minYGap = 2.6;
  const maxYGap = 15;
  let currentPosition = 1.4;
  let totalSpaceRequired = 0;

  const processedEvents = events.map(function (item, index) {
    const currentTimeInSeconds = timeToSeconds(item[2]);
    let gap;

    if (index === 0) {
      gap = 0;
    } else {
      const timeDiffInSeconds = currentTimeInSeconds - prevTimeInSeconds;
      gap = Math.max(
        minYGap,
        Math.min((timeDiffInSeconds / (6 * 3600)) * maxYGap, maxYGap)
      );
    }

    currentPosition += gap;
    prevTimeInSeconds = currentTimeInSeconds;
    return {
      value: [5, currentPosition]
    };
  });

  totalSpaceRequired = currentPosition;
  return { processedEvents, totalSpaceRequired };
}

var option = {
  baseOption: {
    backgroundColor: '#1F2327',
    darkMode: false,
    grid: {
      left: '3%',
      right: '8%',
      bottom: '15%',
      containLabel: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['0', '1', '2', '3', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'],
      axisLabel: { show: false },
      axisLine: { show: false },
      axisTick: { show: false }
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value',
      min: 0,
      max: 24,
      axisLabel: { show: false },
      axisLine: { show: false },
      axisTick: { show: false },
      inverse: true,
      splitLine: { show: false }
    },
    timeline: {
      axisType: 'category',
      data: Object.keys(event_data)
    },
    series: []
  },
  options: []
};

// Populate options for each date
Object.keys(event_data).forEach(function (dateKey) {
  const { processedEvents, totalSpaceRequired } = processData(dateKey);
  let endPercentage = 100;
  if (totalSpaceRequired > maxVisibleYAxisValue) {
    endPercentage = (maxVisibleYAxisValue / totalSpaceRequired) * 100;
  }

  option.options.push({
    dataZoom: [
      {
        type: 'slider',
        yAxisIndex: 0,
        start: 0,
        end: endPercentage,
        filterMode: 'none',
      }
    ],
    series: [
      {
        type: 'line',
        data: processedEvents,
        coordinateSystem: 'cartesian2d',
        symbol: 'circle',
        symbolSize: 20,
        zlevel: 1,
        step: 'middle',
        markLine: {
          silent: true,
          symbol: ['none', 'none'],
          lineStyle: {
            type: 'solid',
            color: '#FFFFFF'
          },
          data: processedEvents.flatMap((item, index) => [
            index % 2 != 0
              ? [
                  {
                    coord: ['2', item.value[1]]
                  },
                  {
                    coord: ['6', item.value[1]]
                  }
                ]
              : [
                  {
                    coord: ['6', item.value[1]]
                  },
                  {
                    coord: ['9', item.value[1]]
                  }
                ]
          ])
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});



Cropped timeline chart:


Not all the data is shown because the y-values are not in the interval 0 to 24; I don't understand what you are computing with those gaps and in what units (is 6 * 3600 correct? but even with 60 * 3600 the max value is exceeding 24); now the max value is 43.419; if you set yAxis.max to 44 instead of 24 you'll see all the points. The height limitation is unrelated; it seems to be caused by the fact that you set grid margins for bottom, (left, right) but not top. If you add a top: 1%, the whole space is used echarts generated codepen.

Thanks @kikon, the issue is indeed of yAxis.max.
